# Density Matrix Renormalization Group (DMRG) and Bethe ansatz for 1D Hubbard model

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, renormalization, many-body, spin-chains

Has Density Matrix Renormalization Group (DMRG) been benchmarked against the exact Bethe ansatz result for the one dimensional Hubbard chain? If yes, then what are the relevant references?

Comment: Have you tried googling those words? For example, one of the first hits: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805123

Comment: Yes I did, have you seen the famous Bethe ansatz paper by Lieb and Wu (1968) that solves the Hubbard model in 1D? This paper doesn't even cite that! DMRG was invented in 1992 by Steven White, which was done on the Heisenberg spin chain. I was expecting Hubbard chain to be addressed pretty soon after that comparing exact results found by Lieb and Wu.  

See this https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.20.1445 .